# For which $[a]_7 ∈ \Bbb Z/7 \Bbb Z$ does $([x]_7)^2 = [a]_7$ have a solution $[x]_7 ∈ \Bbb Z/7 \Bbb Z$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

For this question, I simply need some clarification.
I understand that in $Z$, the equation $x^2 = a$ has a solution only when $a$ is a perfect square (and hence positive) or when $a = 0$.

However, I simply am not able to understand how this works in $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the squares in ${\Bbb Z}_7$: $1^2=1$, $2^2=4$, $3^2= 2$, $4^2=2$, $5^2=4$, $6^2=1$. So for $a=1,2,4$ you have solutions $x$.

---

An integer $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$ if it is congruent to a perfect square modulo $n$; i.e., if there is an integer $x$ such that
$$x^2\equiv a\mod n.$$
Otherwise, $a$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $n$.

There is a whole theory behind this in number theory. Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Comment: This does make a lot of sense. However, why did you stop at 6?

Comment: $7\equiv0 \pmod 7$

Comment: Using this method, I calculated the following:

For a = 0,1,4 we have solutions x for $([x]_8)^2$
For a = 0,1,4,7 we have solutions x for $([x]_9)^2$

Comment: Is that correct or have I missed anything?

Comment: For $a=0,1,2,4$ there are solutions mod 7. Mod 9 is a different story. You need to find the squares.

Comment: I did. For $([x]_9)^2$, $1^2 = 1, 2^2 = 4, 3^2 = 0, ..., 8^2 = 1$. Then, I looked for all solutions as you mentioned in your answer and found that a = 0,1,4,7

Comment: You can shorten the computations writing the elements as $[x]_9=\pm 1,\pm2,\pm 3,\pm4$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but -1, -2, -3 and -4 cannot be answers, right?

Comment: @flutterbug98: modulo 7 we have $-1=6$, $-2=5$, $-3=4$, $-4=3$, $-5=2$, $-6=1$.

Comment: Just to be clear, for mod 7, a can take on more values than 0,1,2,4?
Also, could you please expand on as to why mod 9 is a different case then the other modulo?

Comment: @flutterbug98: please see my comment.